# How to get the url reactively from client-side routing?

Tags: sveltekit

I need to get the url whenever it changes on the client.
There is a built-in store that does exactly that, but it's not reactive towards client-side routing:

```js
import {page} from '$app/stores'
// Outputs what I want, but only from a full page reload
console.log($page.url.pathname)
```

I would like to keep the SPA features while having this working when clicking on an `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does update on client-side routing, you simply just run the statement only once. E.g. try this:

```js
$: console.log($page.url.pathname)
```